# Is flag salutation of temple is equal to Statue (Idol) salutation?

Tags: scripture, gods, prayer, pramana

We used to do salutations (Pranama) to god's idol and do prayer front of it in temple. But what if someone unable to go into temple due any reason and do salutation(Pranama) to flag(Dhawja) hoisted above temple. Is that considered as equal or not ? Is any scripture refer this ?

Comment: yes, idol is u, not object